# Between no busca el primer registro

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla llamada `solicitud` donde los usuarios introducen sus solicitudes de vacaciones. Y tengo la siguiente solicitud:

```
pk_solicitud  |  empleado  | fecha_inicio  |  fecha_fin
=========================================================
    52           usuario1     2018-12-20      2018-12-20
```

Con la sentencia `between` quiero que me seleccione la `solicitud` que entre su `fecha_inicio` y su `fecha_fin` esté el día `2018-12-20` pero no me muestra nada.

Esta es mi sentencia:

```
select pk_solicitud 
from solicitud 
where date('2018-12-20') between fecha_inicio and fecha_fin
```

Comment: los datos de muestra que colocas son los mismos que tienes en tu tabla `empleados`? por que yo repliqué tu ejercicio y me es funcional

Comment: @Aprendiz Sí, son los mismos datos, estoy haciendo pruebas pero a mí no me aparece ninguna `pk_solicitud`

Comment: te comparto este enlace donde tengo una muestra de tu ejercicio: [enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af63fc35f4afdc0225359aef19566ec6), entonces

Comment: @Aprendiz Creo que sé donde está el problema. Mis campos de `fecha_inicio` y `fecha_fin` son de tipo `DATETIME`, porque así los necesito

Comment: bajo esa idea entonces te comparto una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- De la zona de comentarios, nos compartes que las columnas son de tipo `DATETIME` lo cual incluye las horas:minutos:segundos.

Para eso entonces *puedes* pasar ambas columnas: `fecha_incio` y `fecha_fin` por la función `DATE` que del objeto solo toma la parte `date` e ignora el resto.

Tu consulta:

```
SELECT pk_solicitud 
FROM solicitud 
WHERE "2018-12-20" 
BETWEEN date(fecha_inicio) AND date(fecha_fin);
```

- Te comparto en [este enlace](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24a4444b65bc8d9d399b8ef02db82d5e) un ejemplo que te dará una mejor idea de como aplicarlo.

Comment: Funcionó! Muchas gracias!!